# Getting information from a second MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

In my code I would like to use a title attribute as you see in my code `title="'. $title .'"`. For now $title ist not returning anything but it should return a value from the database. The title values are stored into another MySQL table (product_titles).

My goal would be to get the field value of the column "names" from the table "products". If the value of the field is the same as `utf8_encode($row_Bereich2->name)` then it should return the field value of the column "product_title".

```
if(!$result = $db->query("SELECT name FROM produkteguide_kategorien_alle_bereiche WHERE bereich = 2")){
         die('Error');
    }

    while($row_Bereich2 = $result->fetch_object()){

         $Select_Bereich2 .= '<input type="checkbox" id="'. utf8_encode($row_Bereich2->name) .'"><label for="'. utf8_encode($row_Bereich2->name) .'">'. utf8_encode($row_Bereich2->name) .'</label> <div title="'. $title .'" class="info_box">i</div><br>';
    }
```

How would I do this?

Comment: this doesn't help you `die('Error');` this does `mysqli_error($db)` should there be errors.

Comment: how hard is it to `select name, title ...`, then use `$row_Bereich2['title']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LEFT JOIN](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT kat.name, prod.product_title
FROM produkteguide_kategorien_alle_bereiche kat
    LEFT JOIN products prod ON (kat.name = prod.name)
    WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped me a lot!

Comment: left join always save me time!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using PDO (I hope so, otherwise, use it).

Well, in your connection string, when you get connected to the DB with PDO you shall precise that you are using utf-8:

`mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8`

By doing this, you will be able to avoid this kind of thing:

`utf8_encode($row_Bereich2->name)`

And to get an error directly from the database, you may have a look over [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.errorinfo.php).

Comment: Thanks but that's not an answer to my question though.

Comment: True, but for me your question wasn't very clear. That's why I purposed some ways to help you making a cleaner code :) (have a look [here](http://www.phptherightway.com/)